# Combining Two Base Tables with a 1:M relationship Into One View with Distinct Rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, `Students` and `Race`. Each student in the `Students` table has one row. Each student in the `Race` table has multiple rows, one for each race.

I'm trying to combine the tables into a view where I have one row for each student and each of their races are listed in separate columns; for example:

[image: Example]

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you tried select distinct and inner join?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) function with a [INNER JOIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#join-type) to accomplish this:

```
SELECT StudentId
     , FName
     , LName
     , CASE H WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE 'H' END AS [Hispanic]
     , CASE W WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE 'W' END AS [White]
     , CASE B WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE 'B' END AS [Black]
     , CASE A WHEN A THEN NULL ELSE 'A' END AS [Asian]
     , CASE I WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE 'I' END AS [Indian]
 FROM (SELECT s.StudentId, FName, LName, r.[Race Code]
         FROM [Students] AS s
         JOIN [Race] AS r ON r.StudentId = s.StudentId)
PIVOT (COUNT([StudentId])
         FOR [Race Code] IN ([H],[W],[B],[A],[I])) AS p
```

If you are happy with just having the count as the row values then there is no need for the case statements and the query can be simplified to this:

```
SELECT StudentId
     , FName
     , LName
     , [H] AS [Hispanic]
     , [W] AS [White]
     , [B] AS [Black]
     , [A] AS [Asian]
     , [I] AS [Indian]
 FROM (SELECT s.StudentId, FName, LName, r.[Race Code]
         FROM [Students] AS s
         JOIN [Race] AS r ON r.StudentId = s.StudentId)
PIVOT (COUNT([StudentId])
         FOR [Race Code] IN ([H],[W],[B],[A],[I])) AS p
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a solution that looks like this. I like the idea of doing a PIVOT also, I think it'd be much easier to read and probably perform faster. Haven't gotten a chance to check it out yet, but I really appreciate everyone's help with this problem!

[image: Solution]